# Appropriate dataset for restricted maximum likelihood Estimation

Tags: data-request, medical, uses-of-open-data

I need a dataset that works with Restricted Maximum likelihood.

thank you

Comment: Your title is a bit vague and has not yet elicited any constructive remarks. The problem to be solved is not yet clear. One could easily seed the PRNG of a generative [MoG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model#Gaussian_mixture_model) model + nuisance params to produce a synthetic dataset for analysis. It's unclear if you've already done that. You have stated an abstract problem but have not yet offered the motivation. It would help if you would post any code you _have_ written so far, or any published references that you've found relevant to the task at hand.